# retrieving blob data from remote server for android

Tags: android, mysql

here's the problem: i am trying to retrieve blob image from server for my application on android.first problem is that doInBackground returns string but i want to return bitmap.also i am not sure if "bitmapImg =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);" line is correct.please help,thanks in advance.

```
   class blobConnect extends AsyncTask<Boolean, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
String result = null;
InputStream inputStream = null;
Bitmap bitmapImg = null;
//convert response to string
try {

// http post
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://x.x.x.x/android_connect/img.php");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
inputStream= httpEntity.getContent();
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
Log.d("MyApp", "Server encountered an error");
}
bitmapImg =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
Log.d("test", bitmapImg);
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
return bitmapImg;
}
}
}
```

Comment: What about Base64 encoding? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding

Comment: i use decoding for converting string to bitmap to display an image.is it necessary to use base64 encoding also?

Comment: You can let doInBackground return a Bitmap. Change your class declaration accordingly.